# Common Lisp permutation pairs without identical values

Tags: common-lisp, permutation

I'm trying to make a function that, given a list, will return a list of pairs of elements where the two elements are not equal. For example, given the list (1 2 3) it would return ((1 2) (1 3) (2 1) (2 3) (3 1) (3 2)). The code I have now works, but it adds nil to each spot where it would have matching numbers; (1 1) for example.

```
(defun make-permutations-without-identical(list)
(loop for x in list
  append (loop for y in list
               collect (append (if (not (equal x y)) (list x y))))))
```

This code, given (1 2 3) returns (NIL (1 2) (1 3) (2 1) NIL (2 3) (3 1) (3 2) NIL). How do I get rid of the NIL's?

Comment: what purpose is the function APPEND with only one argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the lists generated by the inner loop are fresh, you can **nconc** them.  The **loop** macro has **unless** part so that you can conditionally **collect** parts.  Thus you can just **collect** except when **(equal x y)**:

```
CL-USER> (loop for x in '(1 2 3)
              nconcing (loop for y in '(1 2 3)
                            unless (equal x y)
                            collect (list x y)))
((1 2) (1 3) (2 1) (2 3) (3 1) (3 2))
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I'm a student and our teacher doesn't teach us these things...

Comment: Students should become their own teachers in time.  **LOOP** is complex, be sure to visit [the library](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm#loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see NIL in the result list, just don't *collect* NILs. *Collect* only the items you want to be in the result list.